# '""' is not recognized error when trying to update composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am running PHPstorm and Symfony project and when i try to 'composer update' , it returns error:
 **'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.** 
All PHPstorm settings are fine, i set up php as default interpreter, also all path to composer are good.
My composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "root/my_project_name",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "paragonie/random_compat": "1.2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "curly quotes" make it seem like you probably copy/pasted some code somewhere that had fancy quotes around it

Comment: @Hollings, i restarted PHP storm, it still gives me an error.

Comment: PHPStorm has nothing to do with composer, even if you're using the SSH Shell. Composer commands should be run on the command line.

Comment: @aynber i'm using it from internal terminal. It worked fine with git and composer before i updated PHPstorm to 2017.1.4

Comment: Can you share your `composer.json`?

Comment: @fedeisas did it.

Comment: Are you writing the command without the quotes?? composer update

Comment: @BassemLhm yes, without, `composer update`

Comment: Is that empty key in the script (below `"psr-4"`) intended? It *could* be part of the problem.

Comment: @MCEmperor it did not help me, because i have the same project on my job and there is empty brackets too, but it works here fine.

Comment: just to be clear ?   are you running composer update via cli,   or using the phpstorm gui (clicking it)   which of these 2, if any, do work

Comment: @SamJanssens i'm running it from PHPstorm terminal.

Comment: and it also does not work from the regular terminal (outside of phpstorm)   right ?

Comment: @SamJanssens, right.